# "This should be done immediately the last day of that member of staff." Correct?

Tags: word-choice

This was pointed out as ungrammatical in a process document. Its clumsy, but is it ungrammatical? It is the use of immediately unmediated by something like 'after' which is at issue.

Comment: It's not grammatical. If "the last day of that member of staff" is February 13th, when should "this" be done? The intention of the sentence is crucial to correcting it.

Comment: What @Andrew said. It's General Reference. Replace *"the last day of that member of staff"* with, say, *"tomorrow"* if it's not obvious as it stands.

Answer (score 6):

There's a missing preposition before "the last day".  *By*, *before*, *on*, *after*.  Something.

Also, there's a semantic (not grammatical) mismatch between specifying a deadline and saying it should be done "immediately".

Answer (score 2):

It is not grammatical, in that the noun phrase “the last day of that member of staff” has been tacked onto the sentence after the adverb  *immediately*, in a position where either nothing or a prepositional phrase would be suitable.  Perhaps one of the following forms would work, with choice of form depending on what you mean and what you want to emphasize:

> • X should be done immediately when the last day of Y begins.
>   • X should be done when Y's last day begins.
>   • X should be done during Y's last day.
>   • During Y's last day, X should be done first.

Comment: I think the question should be closed anyway, but I don't see why you should assume the missing "temporal relationship" is *begins*, rather than *ends*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think using *upon* or *during* in place of *immediately* might give the originally-intended meaning.  Absent context, we don't know.  Regarding begins *vs* ends, isn't it perverse to suppose *immediately* means to do something last?

Comment: You miss my point. How can you possibly *know* the "originally-intended meaning". I speak English too, and I don't know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, without context, we don't know the originally-intended meaning.  However, I suspect that the originally-intended meaning is that meaning conveyed by using upon or during in place of immediately.

Comment: I don't know what it means in this context to suspect one interpretation over another. *The text is all*, as the post-modernists would have it. As Malvolio says, there are at least *three* valid interpretations of what it *might* mean, once the missing preposition is added. Without that, it's either ambiguous or simply an invalid utterance, depending on how you look at it.